# Event Sourcing - passing events from AR to entites

Tags: java, events, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I have a problem with more complex Aggregate Root structure and event sourcing. Lets say I have this piece of code:

```
class AggregateRoot{
    Entity entity1;
    Entity entity2;

    //this is returned to service layer to be persisted to db in event stream
    AggregateRootUpdatedState execCommand(int command){
        entity1 = new Entity();
        EntityUpdatedStateEvent event1 = this.entity1.changeState(command);

        EntityUpdatedStateEvent event2 = null;
        if(entity1.state==1) {  //since we already set sub entity - we can check this
            entity2 = new Entity();
            event2 = this.entity2.changeState(command);
        }

        AggregateRootUpdatedState parentEvent = new AggregateRootUpdatedState(event1, event2);
        //when(parentEvent);    //??? WE ALREADY CHANGED STATE IN TWO LINES ABOVE
        return parentEvent;
    }

    void when(AggregateRootUpdatedState event){ //needed for re-hydrating the event state
        entity1 = new Entity();
        entity1.when(event.event1);
        if(event.event2!=null) {
            entity2 = new Entity();
            entity2.when(event.event2);
        }
    }
}

class Entity{
    int state;

    EntityUpdatedStateEvent changeState(int state){
        EntityUpdatedStateEvent event = new EntityUpdatedStateEvent(state);
        when(event);
        return event;
    }

    void when(EntityUpdatedStateEvent event){
        this.state = event.state;
    }
}

class EntityUpdatedStateEvent{
    int state;

    EntityUpdatedStateEvent(int state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}

class AggregateRootUpdatedState{
    EntityUpdatedStateEvent event1; //here we are nesting events AR->Entity
    EntityUpdatedStateEvent event2;

    AggregateRootUpdatedState(EntityUpdatedStateEvent event1, EntityUpdatedStateEvent event2) {
        this.event1 = event1;
        this.event2 = event2;
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is one aggregate root `AggregateRoot` that has 2 sub-entities `entity1` and `entity2`. When AR receives command (in this case simple `int command`) it has to call some methods on sub-entities in order for them to modify their state. As reaction to this, they fire `EntityUpdatedStateEvent` that is automatically applied inside entity by calling `when` method. Applying event at this time guarantees that when entity returns, aggregate root will have correct state set, and I will be able to do comparison test `if(entity1.state==1)` in aggregate root. Depending on this test, I also update other entity state. Both events are then composed into `AggregateRootUpdatedState` event that is preserved to event store.

Now, my question is - in AR I'm not calling `when` method at all for first time `AggregateRootUpdatedState` happens (only on re-hydrating the AR). Is this correct approach since I saw that AR state should also be modified by calling `when` method?

Is there some other way to pass events down the AR hierarchy?

**UPDATE**

```
class AggregateRoot{
    List<SubEntityLevel1> subEntityLevel1s;
    int rootNum;

    void command(int x){
        rootNum = x*x;
        for(int i=0; i<x; i++){
            SubEntityLevel1 subEntityLevel1 = new SubEntityLevel1();
            subEntityLevel1.modify1(i, rootNum);
            subEntityLevel1s.add(subEntityLevel1);
        }
    }

    void when(AggregateRootModifiedEvent event){
        //HOW TO REFACTOR METHOD ABOVE TO EVENT?
    }
}

class SubEntityLevel1{
    int id;
    List<SubEntityLevel2> subEntityLevel2s;
    int sum = 0;

    void modify1(int id, int rootNum){
        //HOW TO MAKE EVENT FROM THIS AND THEN APPLY IN WHEN() METHOD?
        this.id = id;
        this.sum = rootNum;
        for(int i=0; i<id; i++){
            if(subEntityLevel2s.stream().noneMatch(se2 -> "0".equals(se2.id))) {
                SubEntityLevel2 subEntityLevel2 = new SubEntityLevel2();
                subEntityLevel2.modify2(i);
                subEntityLevel2s.add(subEntityLevel2);
                sum++;
            }
        }
    }

    void when(SubEntityLevel1Modified event){
        this.id = event.id;
        this.sum = event.sum;
        for(SubEntityLevel2Modified subEvent : event.subEntity2Events){
            when(subEvent);
        }
    }

    void when(SubEntityLevel2Modified event){
        SubEntityLevel2 subEntityLevel2 = new SubEntityLevel2();
        subEntityLevel2.when(event);
        subEntityLevel2s.add(subEntityLevel2);
    }

    void when(SubEntityLevel2Created event){
        //??????
    }
}

class SubEntityLevel2{
    String id;

    SubEntityLevel2Modified modify2(int x){
        SubEntityLevel2Modified event = new SubEntityLevel2Modified(String.valueOf(x));
        when(event);
        return event;
    }

    void when(SubEntityLevel2Modified event){
        this.id = event.id;
    }
}

//----- EVENTS

class AggregateRootModifiedEvent{
    int rootNum;
    List<SubEntityLevel1Modified> subEntity1Events;

    public AggregateRootModifiedEvent(int rootNum, List<SubEntityLevel1Modified> subEntity1Events) {
        this.rootNum = rootNum;
        this.subEntity1Events = subEntity1Events;
    }
}

class SubEntityLevel1Modified{
    int id;
    List<SubEntityLevel2Modified> subEntity2Events;
    int sum;

    public SubEntityLevel1Modified(int id, List<SubEntityLevel2Modified> subEntity2Events, int sum) {
        this.id = id;
        this.subEntity2Events = subEntity2Events;
        this.sum = sum;
    }
}

class SubEntityLevel2Created{}

class SubEntityLevel2Modified{
    String id;

    SubEntityLevel2Modified(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Since 1st example was more unreal to my real problems, I updated question with this new one where I actually have 3 levels of nesting and with Lists in both of them and some additional logic. I'm basically struggling how to refactor this methods (eg method in `SubEntityLevel1`, `modify1`) to use event sourcing (first creating event and then applying it).

**UPDATE 2**

OK, seems like I have some solution but seems much more complex than without event sourcing in place...

```
class AggregateRoot{
    List<SubEntityLevel1> subEntityLevel1s = new ArrayList<>();
    int rootNum;

    List<Object> command(int x){
        List<Object> tempEvents = new ArrayList<>();
        //rootNum = x*x;
        int tempRootNum = x*x;
        for(int i=0; i<x; i++){
            SubEntityLevel1 subEntityLevel1 = new SubEntityLevel1();
            List<Object> subEvents = subEntityLevel1.modify1(i, tempRootNum);
            //subEntityLevel1s.add(subEntityLevel1);
            SubEntityLevel1Added event = new SubEntityLevel1Added(subEvents);
            when(event);
            tempEvents.add(event);
        }
        AggregateRootModifiedEvent event = new AggregateRootModifiedEvent(tempRootNum);
        when(event);
        tempEvents.add(event);
        return tempEvents;
    }

    void when(AggregateRootModifiedEvent event){
        this.rootNum = event.rootNum;
    }

    void when(SubEntityLevel1Added event){
        SubEntityLevel1 subEntityLevel1 = new SubEntityLevel1();
        for(Object subEvent : event.events){
            subEntityLevel1.when(subEvent); //list of SubEntityLevel2Added AND SubEntityLevel1Initialized
        }
        subEntityLevel1s.add(subEntityLevel1);
    }
}

class SubEntityLevel1{
    int id;
    List<SubEntityLevel2> subEntityLevel2s = new ArrayList<>();
    int sum = 0;

    List<Object> modify1(int id, int rootNum){
        //this.id = id;
        //this.sum = rootNum;
        int tempSum = rootNum;
        List<Object> tempEvents = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<id; i++){
            if(subEntityLevel2s.stream().noneMatch(se2 -> "0".equals(se2.id))) {

                SubEntityLevel2 subEntityLevel2 = new SubEntityLevel2();
                SubEntityLevel2Initialized event = subEntityLevel2.initialize(i);
                //subEntityLevel2s.add(subEntityLevel2);
                SubEntityLevel2Added event2 = new SubEntityLevel2Added(event);
                when(event2);
                tempEvents.add(event2);

                //sum++;
                tempSum++;
            }
        }
        SubEntityLevel1Initialized event3 = new SubEntityLevel1Initialized(id, tempSum);
        when(event3);
        tempEvents.add(event3);
        return tempEvents;
    }

    void when(SubEntityLevel1Initialized event){
        this.id = event.id;
        this.sum = event.sum;
    }

    void when(SubEntityLevel2Added event){
        SubEntityLevel2 subEntityLevel2 = new SubEntityLevel2();
        subEntityLevel2.when(event.event);
        subEntityLevel2s.add(subEntityLevel2);
    }
}

class SubEntityLevel2{
    String id;

    SubEntityLevel2Initialized initialize(int x){
        SubEntityLevel2Initialized event = new SubEntityLevel2Initialized(String.valueOf(x));
        when(event);
        return event;
    }

    void when(SubEntityLevel2Initialized event){
        this.id = event.id;
    }
}

//----- EVENTS

class AggregateRootModifiedEvent{
    int rootNum;

    public AggregateRootModifiedEvent(int rootNum) {
        this.rootNum = rootNum;
    }
}

class SubEntityLevel1Added{
    List<Object> events;

    public SubEntityLevel1Added(List<Object> events) {
        this.events = events;
    }
}

class SubEntityLevel1Initialized {
    int id;
    int sum;

    public SubEntityLevel1Initialized(int id, int sum) {
        this.id = id;
        this.sum = sum;
    }
}

class SubEntityLevel2Added{
    SubEntityLevel2Initialized event;

    public SubEntityLevel2Added(SubEntityLevel2Initialized event) {
        this.event = event;
    }
}

class SubEntityLevel2Initialized {
    String id;

    SubEntityLevel2Initialized(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Both events are then composed into AggregateRootUpdatedState event that is preserved to event store.

That looks to me like an anti pattern; you can make it work for version 1 of your model, but it introduces a bunch of extra work when you want to start refactoring, or responding to events.  You should probably be thinking in terms of returning collections of events, rather than a single monolithic event.

Your aggregate code would then look like

```
History execCommand(int command){
    entity1 = new Entity();
    EntityUpdatedStateEvent event1 = this.entity1.changeState(command);

    EntityUpdatedStateEvent event2 = null;
    if(entity1.state==1) {  //since we already set sub entity - we can check this
        entity2 = new Entity();
        event2 = this.entity2.changeState(command);
    }

    // ALL of the state changes have already happened, so no need to
    // re-process the events.
    return History.of(event1, event2)
}
```

Another thing to notice is that, in this example, you have been changing the root entity without producing events, specifically when you have been creating the child events

```
    entity1 = new Entity();
```

Why isn't the beginning of the entity's lifecycle an explicit thing in your model?  There should be an event for that, ensuring that the entity references (this.entity1, this.entity2) are always assigned the same way.

```
EntityOneCreatedEvent createEntityOne() {
    EntityOneCreatedEvent e = new EntityOneCreatedEvent();
    when(e);
    return e;
}
```

> Is there some other way to pass events down the AR hierarchy?

One approach is to use Meyer's [command query separation](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html) pattern, and separate the logic for creating the event(s) from the logic of updating the entity states.
The basic idea would be that in a query, you never change your own state (you might make a copy of your state, and change the copy); in the command, you apply the changes to your local state.

If you think of state as an immutable value type, this pattern really flows naturally out of it.

Comment: Thanks for response. Could you please check my updated question, since it now reflects more realistically my problem. I agree that I should probably have this CreatedEvent (but in my new question above I don't know how to reference it afterwards). Also, as you replied in first code snippet - Aggregate root in the end does not need to apply events when executing for the first time - only when re-hydrating. Is there any example of Meyer's pattern in relation to event sourcing?

Comment: I'll take a look -- as a general hint, however: any time you are asking about DDD, you should hew as closely as you can to your real problem.  Generically domains with generic constraints are really hard to model intelligently.